# Custom button to copy field values from other object

Tags: custom-button, opportunity, contracts

we have created an APEX class that creates a contract object from an opportunity object. We need to create a custom button on contract object to copy some field values from the related opportunity object to the new contract object and I do not really how to do it. This step is not mandatory (for this reason I have not include that in the apex class), it is just an option for the users and has to be done always once the contract object has been already created. I have in a custom contract field the associated opportunity id. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running apex from a custom button is a fairly common requirement. The trick is if you need it to be protected against CSRF or included as part of a managed package.

At the simplest level you can create a custom button link on Contract to custom Visualforce page that takes the Contract ID as a query string parameter. The custom Visualforce page will then use the action attribute of the apex:page to fire a method in the controller. The method returns a PageReference that redirects back to the Contract when complete. See an example at: 
[Custom Button or Link to a Visualforce page with a custom controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8497639/54026?stw=2)

Making it work in a CSRF safe way with managed packages is a bit more tricky. Last I checked you need an intermediate page or a custom Contract Detail page. See [CSRF safe Custom button linked to Apex method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10809520/54026?stw=2)

Alternatively, you could expose your apex method as a webservice method and then invoke it using sforce.apex.execute via a javascript button. This isn't ideal if you don't want others to be able to call the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

You should just start by looking at [Ray Dehler's URL Hacking post](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html) . This was all I needed to read up on URL hacking and custom buttons.  If all you are doing is creating a contract from the opportunity and either copying values from it or hardcoding then this should be enough reading..

Comment: URL hacking is unsupported, won't work via Salesforce1, and is generally a bad idea, especially if you're already using apex in your org!

Comment: Yeah of course it's unsupported,but I've used pretty successfully over the years in a pretty large org and don't remember any huge problems regarding the use thereof.
Salesforce do provide Chatter Actions that are able to do mostly the same thing, otherwise it's just a matter of writing an apex class and having a button that uses OnClick Javascript and calling the class.
I use a mixture of both.  Whatever works.